# Bsd socket how can I find server port number for connection?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I have a server:

> ./server portNumber

I have a client:

> ./client serverIpAddress

I have only server Ip Address in the client. I want to connect to Server socket. But every time Server Port Number is different. How Can I connect to server socket with BSD Socket in the client? Is it impossible? Do I have to know server port number?

Simple Usage BSD Socket:

```
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipAddress);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( ThisIsServerPortNumber );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Where's your C code where you set up the socket? Your question is a bit unclear. Or do you want to find it from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a [port number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) between 49152 and 65535 for development. If your idea is successful, you'll want to register a port number between 1024 and 49151. Port numbers from 0 to 1023 are well-known ports, e.g. port 80 is for HTTP servers.

The [TCP Port Service Multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Port_Service_Multiplexer) protocol was intended to allow discovery of port numbers for TCP servers, but it's seldom used due to security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

The `bind(2)` system call is used to select a port number in a server.  It has to be called before the `listen(2)` system call and after the `socket(2)` call.

It allows to specify, not only the port number the server is going to listen for connections, *but also the ip address* in case the host has several interfaces and you want only to accept connections in one of the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

> But every time Server Port Number is different. How Can I connect to
>   server socket with BSD Socket in the client? … Do I have to know
>   server port number?

Yes, you have to know it. Think: There can be many different server programs running on the server host, bound to many different ports. A client computer has no simple insight into the server host to see to which port the desired server program is bound. Thus, it is usual to use a preassigned port number in the server as well as in the client.